# Newton Raphson Method Overestimating Parameters

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

I have implemented an almost plain vanilla algorithm to find the MLE estimates of 3 parameters in a log-likelihood function (in R.) When I test my algorithm with some simulated data it does pretty well PROVIDED that the starting values for the parameters are all 3 below the actually values (that I used to simulate the data.) As soon as even one of the starting values is larger than the actual value (which I used in my simulator) than the algorithm goes crazy and ends up giving some totally wrong estimates.

My question is: where is the problem? Is it a *mathematical* problem related to some weakness of the Newton Raphson method or is it a coding/implementation problem?

Comment: The Newton-Raphson method does not guarantee convergence to the global maximum for *any* starting point (unless the function is "well behaved", e.g., it is convex). The wrong estimates you get correspond to some local maximum of the log-likelihood into which the algorithm gets "trapped" due to the starting point being closer to that than the global maximum (assuming coding/implementation are correct).

Comment: @Stelios: thanks for your feedback! Unfortunately the local maxima it seems to get trapped is miles away from the starting values: in essence, it seems like the algorithm fails to look for values smaller than the starting one... I just wanted to double check whether this is a well know issue with the method or something I should look more into (from the implementation side)

Comment: The algorithm's behavior is indeed strange, however, it may be the case that you are dealing with a nasty function. Plotting a few realizations of the log-likelihood function would give you some indication if this is the case. You may also try double-checking your results with someone else's implementation of the algorithm (e.g., using one from a computational software program)

Comment: @Stelios: the idea of plotting the log-likelihood function is great: I will most definitely do it! I have also already double-checked with the pre-existing `R` functions that perform such task and found that it is my implementation that fails. However, the documentation on what specific implementation of NR is used by such packages is pretty lacking so I'm left wondering whether my method fails because of a coding error or because it uses a *plain vanilla* implementation that is just not good enough for more nasty functions...

Comment: hhmm... coming to think about it: how can I plot a function of 3 variables? I have 3 parameters in my log-likelihood function :(

Comment: Just fix one of the variables (say, at its actual value), then you have a 2 variable plot. The behavior of this plot would provide some indication (not proof!) of the behavior of the function when all three variables are free.